# How to map form input to the list in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl, spring-form

I am trying to map the form to the modelAttribute containing list in it. It is throwing me null pointer exception. please help.

This is my model

```
public class FamilyDetails {

    private String spousesName;
    private int spousesAge;
    private String fatherName;
    private String motherName;
    private String fatherAge;
    private String motherAge;
    private long emergencyNumber;
    private String weddingDate;
    private List<ChildrenDetails> childrenDetails;
```

.....

this contains a list of childrenDetails model

my children details model is

```
public class ChildrenDetails {

    private String childName;
    private String childGender;
    private String childDob;
    private String childCompanyName;
    private String childPosition;
```

....

I want to set the values taking it from my spring form tags in jsp and binded it to my model.
So this is what I did

```
<tr>
                        <c:set value="${family.childrenDetails}" var="child"/>
                        <td>childname:<input type="text" value="${child.childName}"/></td>
                        <td>childGender:<input type="text" value="${child.childGender}"> </td>
                        <td>childDob:<input type="text" value="${child.childDob}"> </td>
                        <td>childCompanyName:<input type="text" value="${child.childCompanyName}"> </td>
                        <td>childPosition:<input type="text" value="${child.childPosition}"> </td>
</tr>
```

Every time I change something I am getting different type of exceptions.
please tell me what is the correct way to bind the model to the values that I am sending from UI

Comment: You aren't binding anything, use the Spring form tags for this and not plain input tags. Currently a random id/name is generated which doesn't match your property names so basically nothing is going to happen nor anything will be bound. Also you are binding the full collection to a single element not going to work either. I strongly suggest a read on how the spring form tags work and how JSTL works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ModelAttribute` annotation in method level parameter. It binds the values with your `FamilyDetails` Domain model object.

```
    public String methodName(@ModelAttribute(value="familyDetails") FamilyDetails familyDetails, BindingResult result)
    {
      if (!result.hasErrors()){
           /* action */

      } else {
           /* Binding result error */
           return "Failed";
        }
    return "viewPage";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before rendering a input UI page you need to pass an empty FamilyDetails object to the form so that spring form tag library can bind all the input values to the FamilyDetails object.

```
 @RequestMapping(/UIurl)
    public String renderUI(ModelMap model)
    {
    model.addAttribute("FamilyDetails", new FamilyDetails());
    return "InputUIPage";
    }
```

InputUIPage

Use Spring form tag library; modelAttribute will bind all the input fields to the model

```
<form:form modelAttribute="FamilyDetails" action=""/>
```

Access the input values in the Controller for further processing

```
@RequestMapping(/formActionurl)
    public String renderUI(@ModelAttribute("FamilyDetails") FamilyDetails familyData)
    {
    String spouseName = familyData.getSpousesName();
    //
    }
```

Check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/) out